# Which layout (AbsoluteLayout etc) is best for simple game programming in the android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, absolutelayout

There are the following layout options to create interfaces for android.

```
AbsoluteLayout
FrameLayout
LinearLayout
TableLayout
RelativeLayout (and some more)
```

Which of the following is most suitable for designing simple games? Guessing that the absoluteLayout is easiest, but will it be problems with different screen sizes? What do you recommend?

Comment: Don't games draw pixels directly to the canvas?  Never heard of a game using a layout manager.

Comment: I am thinking of a very simple game with ImageView and images

Comment: It depends on what you're doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AbsoluteLayout will give you the most control where your views will be placed. However I recommend using RelativeLayout. This will be much more screen size and density independed.

You can use different layouts for different screen sizes or densities. Also make sure not to place your views using abosolute pixels (px), rather use device independet pixels (dp or dip). Those will be automatically scaled for different densities.

There is a lot about this in the official docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

I've been avoiding AbsoluteLayout, because it's deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html

Comment: Do you also recommend relative layout?

Are the other options in addition to absolute layout ok to use or they can also cause problems?